# passing variables from php to Javascript or ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

So I have a three files html, JS, and PHP; I just created a simple registration page, I'm new to php so I'm still learning, however; when the user click on the register button it will redirect him to the php file to save everything to the database, and then it will redirect him to the same registration page, everything is working well, but I created a small div which will show a message "Registered Successfully", when the user comeback to the registration page, I hide this div using simple CSS `visibility:hidden;`, and  I made an onload function that will check a global variable so that the site will know whither to show the div or not, the only thing that I don't know how to do is to change the global varible from false to true from the PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using this code it is working right fOR ME.

```
function my_admin_head() {

        $VAR = 'OK';
        ?>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
                        var my_var = 
                        {
                        'dynamicvalues':<?php echo $VAR;;?>
                        };
        </script> 
 <?php
}
```

and then access in js

```
alert(my_var.dynamicvalues);
```

Comment: but i want to do the php and the js parts separably, I mean I wan to do this   from the php file not from the js file

Answer (score 0):

That is not the best way to do such things.
The better is to show the div in your php template using a $var.
So your script send $var to include 'yourtemplatepage.php';
In your template:

```
<?php 
 if (isset($var) {
  echo "<div>YOUR MESSAGE</div>";
} 
?>
```

To change the var, do the same.
in your JS script

```
var boolean = '<?php echo $var ?>';
```

Comment: you want me to do this in the PHP file?

Comment: Depending if your template is actually php file. That way does not just hide in css the div never being written to Dom if the condition is false.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the concept of cookie.
From php set a document cookie and in javascript read the value of that cookie.

**PHP**

```
<?php
 setcookie("registration", true, time()+3600); // expires in one hour
?>
```

**JS**

```
var cookies = document.cookie;
var registrationCookie = cookies.split('=')[1];
```